# UIScrollView and UITableView do not work

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` into a `UIScrollView` and I need that this table does not have scroll, because all of view are going to scrolling, I am using the method `-reset_sizes` to do this, but do not work, this just scroll all content_view but the frame of the table do not change, I am trying to change the height of the table but it does not work.

Somebody knows what can be the problem?

```
-(void) reset_sizes
{
        [_scroll_view layoutIfNeeded];


        _table_view.frame = CGRectMake(_table_view.frame.origin.x, _table_view.frame.origin.y, _table_view.frame.size.width, [list_elements_to_table count]*44);

        NSInteger height = _table_view.frame.size.height +_content_summary.frame.size.height+_content_apis.frame.size.height+_content_tag.frame.size.height;

        _content_view.frame = CGRectMake(_content_view.frame.origin.x, _content_view.frame.origin.y, _content_view.frame.size.width, _content_view.frame.origin.y+height);

        _scroll_view.contentSize = _content_view.bounds.size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable scrolling on a UITableView with `_table_view.scrollEnabled = NO`
As far as why your code is not changing the height of the tableView? Try calling `-layoutIfNeeded` after adjusting the frames/sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your commet but this does not work, for example the content size have de correct height. But the table continue with the scroll.

Comment: Is it the tableView that is scrolling or the scollView that the table is contained in?

Answer (score 0):

disable the tableView scrollEnabled property by using self.tableview.scrollEnabled=NO